# Segmentation Fault when requiring mysql2 gem

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, mysql2, ruby-1.9.2

I had been developing a rails app in development using 1.8.7 and now am trying to switch to 1.9.2 (using RVM).

However, after switching rubies, installing rails, and bundling my app, running 'rails s' incurs this error (require 'mysql2' in irb gives the same error):

> /Users/kmurph79/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle:
>   [BUG] Segmentation fault ruby
>   1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-darwin10.6.0]

Full output:

```
-- control frame ----------
c:0030 p:-541397022 s:0092 b:0092 l:000091 d:000091 TOP   
c:0029 p:---- s:0090 b:0090 l:000089 d:000089 CFUNC  :require
c:0028 p:0012 s:0086 b:0086 l:000070 d:000085 BLOCK  /Users/kmurph79/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239
c:0027 p:0005 s:0084 b:0084 l:000075 d:000083 BLOCK  /Users/kmurph79/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225
c:0026 p:0045 s:0082 b:0082 l:000081 d:000081 METHOD /Users/kmurph79/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596
c:0025 p:0041 s:0076 b:0076 l:000075 d:000075 METHOD /Users/kmurph79/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225
c:0024 p:0013 s:0071 b:0071 l:000070 d:000070 METHOD /Users/kmurph79/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239
c:0023 p:0072 s:0066 b:0066 l:000065 d:000065 TOP    /Users/kmurph79/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2.rb:7
c:0022 p:---- s:0064 b:0064 l:000063 d:000063 FINISH
c:0021 p:---- s:0062 b:0062 l:000061 d:000061 CFUNC  :require
c:0020 p:0026 s:0058 b:0058 l:000039 d:000057 BLOCK  /Users/kmurph79/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68
c:0019 p:---- s:0055 b:0055 l:000054 d:000054 FINISH
c:0018 p:---- s:0053 b:0053 l:000052 d:000052 CFUNC  :each
c:0017 p:0091 s:0050 b:0050 l:000039 d:000049 BLOCK  /Users/kmurph79/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66
c:0016 p:---- s:0045 b:0045 l:000044 d:000044 FINISH
c:0015 p:---- s:0043 b:0043 l:000042 d:000042 CFUNC  :each
c:0014 p:0046 s:0040 b:0040 l:000039 d:000039 METHOD /Users/kmurph79/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55
c:0013 p:0021 s:0036 b:0036 l:000035 d:000035 METHOD /Users/kmurph79/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler.rb:120
c:0012 p:0079 s:0032 b:0032 l:000031 d:000031 TOP    /Users/kmurph79/Documents/Rails_Projects/SmugFolio2/config/application.rb:7
c:0011 p:---- s:0030 b:0030 l:000029 d:000029 FINISH
c:0010 p:---- s:0028 b:0028 l:000027 d:000027 CFUNC  :require
c:0009 p:0016 s:0024 b:0024 l:000015 d:000023 BLOCK  /Users/kmurph79/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:28
c:0008 p:---- s:0021 b:0021 l:000020 d:000020 FINISH
c:0007 p:---- s:0019 b:0019 l:000018 d:000018 CFUNC  :tap
c:0006 p:0468 s:0016 b:0016 l:000015 d:000015 TOP    /Users/kmurph79/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:27
c:0005 p:---- s:0012 b:0012 l:000011 d:000011 FINISH
c:0004 p:---- s:0010 b:0010 l:000009 d:000009 CFUNC  :require
c:0003 p:0061 s:0006 b:0006 l:0014e8 d:0024c8 EVAL   script/rails:6
c:0002 p:---- s:0004 b:0004 l:000003 d:000003 FINISH
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 b:0002 l:0014e8 d:0014e8 TOP   
---------------------------
-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
script/rails:6:in `'
script/rails:6:in `require'
/Users/kmurph79/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `'
/Users/kmurph79/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
/Users/kmurph79/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `block in '
/Users/kmurph79/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `require'
/Users/kmurph79/Documents/Rails_Projects/SmugFolio2/config/application.rb:7:in `'
/Users/kmurph79/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `require'
/Users/kmurph79/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
/Users/kmurph79/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
/Users/kmurph79/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
/Users/kmurph79/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
/Users/kmurph79/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/Users/kmurph79/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
/Users/kmurph79/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2.rb:7:in `'
/Users/kmurph79/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
/Users/kmurph79/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
/Users/kmurph79/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/kmurph79/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
/Users/kmurph79/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'
/Users/kmurph79/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

Abort trap
```

Mysql is installed via homebrew and was working fine under 1.8.7, but perhaps I need to install a new mysql version?  I dunno.

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: I think you might need to recompile the mysql gem, try deleting the gem and installing it again... Unfortunately integration between ruby and mysql is one of the most painful experiences I've had :(

Comment: Did you by any chance copied gemsets between 1.8 and 1.9?

Comment: This just happened to me when I tried to simultaneously gem install rails and mysql2. When I uninstalled and reinstalled the mysql2 adapter, it fixed it.

Comment: install libmariadbclient-dev package and reinstall the gem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by downloading the latest version of MySQL.